# How to download the current document's innerHTML as a file?

Tags: javascript, download, dispatchevent

Is there a way I could download the current document's `innerHTML` as file **programmatically**?

I've made the following attempt without success. It does download the current document's source, however that's not what I am looking for, since **I want to preserve any post-load document modifications**.

```
 var save = document.createElement('a');
 save.href = "my location href.attr";
 save.target = '_blank';
 save.download = fileName || 'unknown';

 var event = document.createEvent('Event');
 event.initEvent('click', true, true);
 save.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve, despite your explanations. Could you try with other words?

Comment: OK! I just want to save my page with dispatchEvent after some inline changing. but when i use href for it, it use a base html.

Comment: Sounds like you need something like onClick and preventDefault() ? Unclear tho...

Comment: @saeedhbi Would you mind if I re-write the question? I think others would have a better chance of finding the answer if they do have the same question.

Comment: Yes, no problem. If you get better idea i'm glad to use it :)

Comment: seems you got your answer!

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani Yes afshin. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps something like this? It's probably not very cross-browser however, but it works in Chrome.

```js
function downloadCurrentDocument() {
  var base64doc = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.innerHTML))),
      a = document.createElement('a'),
      e = new MouseEvent('click');

  a.download = 'doc.html';
  a.href = 'data:text/html;base64,' + base64doc;
  a.dispatchEvent(e);
}
    
downloadCurrentDocument();
```

Comment: Thank you. This is my answer.

Comment: @saeedhbi I'm glad I could help. I was quite puzzled with this one for a moment ;)

Comment: :) Than you for your time.

Comment: @plalx Yes! Firefox:52.0.2