# How to Download and SVG element as an SVG file

Tags: javascript, svg

Over the past few months, I have been working on this code that deals with ellipsoidal earth and just recently I have finished it. My professor now wants me to send him pictures of the diagrams I made as an SVG file. I know in Python you can put a few lines of code into your project to have it download the image, but I am unsure how it works in `JavaScript`. How can I do this in `JavaScript`, or is there another easier way?

Comment: Dear @Paankey56, when you write this code, you should insert it here, we wanna see which code.

Comment: I didn't realize, do you mean you just wanna convert your SVG to a JPG or PNG file to send to your master?

Comment: Eh, I may be missing your context here, but can't you send him the SVG file?

Comment: Does your professor want your code to include the javascript to save?  If not, then why not just go into your browser's console tools (hit F12) and cut and paste the SVG to a new file?

Comment: @Paankey56 See my demo (and answer below) to download as .svg or .png (note that .svg can be taken from inspecting the DOM and doing copy paste as the comments suggest) - https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/VwLaaPe

Answer (score 6):

Check out this demo: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/VwLaaPe?editors=1010

Code (modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19885344/9792594):

```
function downloadSVGasTextFile() {
  const base64doc = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('svg').outerHTML)));
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  const e = new MouseEvent('click');

  a.download = 'download.svg';
  a.href = 'data:text/html;base64,' + base64doc;
  a.dispatchEvent(e);
}

downloadSVGasTextFile();
```

You encode your svg as a 64bit string and then use that as the href of an anchor tag and then dispatch a click event to download the svg text file as download.svg

If you want to save an image, such as .png then you can first draw svg image into a cnavas then download that as .png,

**UPDATE**

I modified the answer and the demo to now include both download as text file .svg or download as image file .png https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/VwLaaPe:

HTML:

```
<svg>
 ...
</svg>
<br/>
<button id="downloadPNG">Download .png</button>
<button id="downloadSVG">Download .svg</button>
```

JS:

```
function downloadSVGAsText() {
  const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
  const base64doc = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg.outerHTML)));
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  const e = new MouseEvent('click');
  a.download = 'download.svg';
  a.href = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + base64doc;
  a.dispatchEvent(e);
}

function downloadSVGAsPNG(e){
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
  const base64doc = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg.outerHTML)));
  const w = parseInt(svg.getAttribute('width'));
  const h = parseInt(svg.getAttribute('height'));
  const img_to_download = document.createElement('img');
  img_to_download.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + base64doc;
  console.log(w, h);
  img_to_download.onload = function () {    
    canvas.setAttribute('width', w);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', h);
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    context.drawImage(img_to_download,0,0,w,h);
    const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(canvas.msToBlob(), "download.png");
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      const my_evt = new MouseEvent('click');
      a.download = 'download.png';
      a.href = dataURL;
      a.dispatchEvent(my_evt);
    }
    //canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
  }  
}

const downloadSVG = document.querySelector('#downloadSVG');
downloadSVG.addEventListener('click', downloadSVGAsText);
const downloadPNG = document.querySelector('#downloadPNG');
downloadPNG.addEventListener('click', downloadSVGAsPNG);
```

Comment: Not sure on the purpose of `unescape` and `encodeURIComponent` here.

Comment: This feels like a lifetime ago now, lol. I’ll take a look and try to understand why

Comment: `msSaveblob` is also [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/msSaveBlob)